# Implement an interface consuming and returning the same interface in C#

Tags: c#, interface

I am having trouble implementing an interface with C#:

```cs
    public interface IFooable
    {
        public (IFooable left, IFooable right) FooWith(IFooable other);
    }
```

And then in my concrete class, I have

```cs
class Concrete
{
        public (Concrete left, Concrete right) FooWith(Concrete other)
        {
            return GoFooSomewhereElse(...);
        }
}
```

But in my tests, the compiler tells me that `Concrete` does not implement the FooWith function.

I don't really understand what is going on, since I am so new at C# and easily confused by the language!

I found similar questions (eg [Why can't I override my interface methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273352/why-cant-i-override-my-interface-methods)) but they did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://www.alpharithms.com/liskov-substitution-principle-lsp-solid-114908/), a superclass object should be replaceable with a subclass object without breaking the functionality of the software.

Your `Concrete` class apparently doesn't implement the interface, because if I try to pass the argument of some `AnotherFooable` class to `FooWith()` method it will not work.

Instead you could make it generic:

```cs
public interface IFooable<T>
{
    public (T left, T right) FooWith(T other);
}

class Concrete : IFooable<Concrete>
{
    public (Concrete left, Concrete right) FooWith(Concrete other)
    {
        return GoFooSomewhereElse(...);
    }
}
```

Also you can put the restriction to the generic type argument, if you want `FooWith()` method to accept only arguments of the same class (as in your example, where you have `Concrete.FooWith(Concrete, Concrete)`):

```cs
public interface IFooable<T> where T : IFooable<T>
...
```

Comment: Nice explanation with Liskov! I did not think seing the problem this way, it definitely makes its resolution clearer! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this trick with generic:

```
public interface IFooable<T>
{
    public (T left, T right) FooWith(T other);
}

class Concrete : IFooable<Concrete>
{
    public (Concrete left, Concrete right) FooWith(Concrete other)
    {
        return GoFooSomewhereElse(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to modify all the consume point of `IFooable` to convert it to `IFooable<T>` but it works very smoothely! :D